# How to ignore specific char while reading SpeechSynthesizer C#?

Tags: c#, output, voice, speech-synthesis

I have some string which goes as follows

```
TEST___5____345
```

How can I make SpeechSynthesizer to ignore the underscore chars while reading, as its annoying ?

Comment: Change the string before it's read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below splits your string using the underscore as the separator. Adding the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries removes all empty string that would occur when multiple sequential underscores are in your inputstring.

```
using System;

namespace IgnoreUnderscore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var str ="TEST___5____345";

            var arr = str.Split(new char[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

---

```
TEST
5
345
```

---